# Mono for Android Calendar

Tags: c#, calendar, monodevelop, xamarin.android

I want to call some calendar app into my aplication, does anybody knows how to do it? I have this code on Java that i have trasnlated to c#  but doenst work at all.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
                Intent intentCalendar = new Intent(Intent.ActionEdit);
                intentCalendar.SetType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                intentCalendar.PutExtra("beginTime", date.Millisecond);
                intentCalendar.PutExtra("allDay", true);
                intentCalendar.PutExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
                intentCalendar.PutExtra("endTime", date.Millisecond + 60*60*1000);
                intentCalendar.PutExtra("title", "Create an Event");
                StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"? Does nothing show up? Does it crash? Can you post the errors from logcat?

Comment: Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: Exception of type 'Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException' was thrown.

Comment: Which version of Android are you testing on? I just tried your code with 2.3 targeting 2.2 and it works fine.

Comment: I did the same thing as you, using an emulator 2.3 targeting 2.2, but for me doesnt work...How did you make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StartActivity(intentCalendar);
```

instead of

```
StartActivity(intent);
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Change your last line.

```
StartActivity (intent);
```

to:

```
StartActivity (intentCalendar);
```

Otherwise, good job.

Edit: Sorry for the repeat, I just saw the other answer provided. I just poked around with your code and found it works for me with that change, but I see someone else also came to that conclusion.